# GUI is just showing one number

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I have a problem, i using Swing and AWT to create a calculator with differnt functions, for example when i click "Sieve of Eratosthenes" the output of 10 have to be 2 3 5 7, but in the result JTextArea i see only the last number, in this case 7, however if i use "System.out.print(i + " ");" in the console i can see 2 3 5 7.

```
{
...
result.setText(String.valueOf(i + " "));
}
```

Comment: [`JTextArea.append()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String))

Comment: Or if you use `JTextField`, then use `textField.setText(textField.getText()+value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JTextArea result is updated with new value every time you call

```
result.setText(String.valueOf(i + " "));
```

You may want to update existing value by calling:

```
result.setText(result.getText() + String.valueOf(i + " "));
```

Comment: Use the `append(...)` method which was designed for this. It is not efficient to replace the entire text every time.